# Proving open balls in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ are convex

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $r > 0$. I have shown that for every $\textbf{u}, \textbf{v} \in B_r(\textbf{x})$ and $t \in (0,1)$, $t\textbf{u} + (1-t)\textbf{v} \in B_r(\textbf{x})$.

This is because $|tu + (1-t)v - x| = |tu + (1-t)v -x + tx - tx|  = |t(u-x) + (1-t)(v-x)| \leq |t(u-x)| + |(1-t)(v-x)| = t|u-x| + (1-t)|v-x| < tr + (1-t)r = r$.

So $tu + (1-t)v \in B_r(x)$. But how come this proof doesn't show that all points on the line connecting $u$ and $v$ are in the open ball around $x$? We chose $t$ to be arbitrary, but I don't see any special properties that only work for reals between zero and one. If we let $t = 500$, the proof still seems to hold, yet that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Have you tried plugging $t=500$ into the proof and seeing what it looks like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's here: The statement

$$|t(u−x)|+|(1−t)(v−x)|=t|u−x|+(1−t)|v−x|$$

is not true except for $t \in (0,1)$.

Instead it's

$$|t(u−x)|+|(1−t)(v−x)|=|t| |u−x|+|1−t| |v−x|$$

and so if $t<0$ or $t>1$ you couldn't drop the absolute values.

Answer (score 2):

If $t<0$, $|t| = t$ will not hold.

If $t>1$, $|1-t| = 1-t$ will not hold.